# Is it possible to play video with audio on a single processor computer which can run only one process at a time

Tags: process, operating-system, cpu-architecture

From what I know about processors and it's working, one processor can run one process at a time.
So for a task like playing video which have more than one component like playing video and audio that should happen at the same time, is single processor computer is able to do tasks like this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, video playback worked just fine on single-core computers from the early 2000s, like my old AMD K8 or (at lower resolution) my Intel PIII 450 MHz.

Audio can decode into a buffer that the sound card reads on its own; you don't need a CPU core feeding one sample at a time at 48 kHz.

The video frame interval is typically like 33 ms (for 30fps video), which is longer than a couple OS scheduling timeslices.  So there's plenty of time to decode a frame of video and `nanosleep()` until it's time to display it, e.g. by changing a pointer if your video output is truly double buffered, or with GPU-accelerated video scaling, or just software copying.

So the timing requirements are loose enough that context switching on a mainstream non-realtime OS doesn't have much of a problem, although the occasional stutter in video playback was possible if you were doing something else CPU intensive if your CPU was just barely fast enough to run the software decode in real-time.

Some keywords for learning more:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch
- pre-emptive multi-tasking: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#PREEMPTIVE